# Part of my model won't show in cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been working on this mesh for a while now and finally got around to rendering it.

However when I attempt to do a test render the feet wont show in the render. I double checked to make sure that it will show to the camera. And verified that it isn't hidden in render.

It shows in object view

[image]

However not during render

[image]

I'm not really certain what else I should attempt to do.

Here is my blend file which you can use.

[Mech.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rd80ah17modfjem/Mechtutorial.blend?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set duplication in object panel to none, you have set it to group. When the duplication is active the parent doesn't render

Comment: Dude thank you so much i would have never thought that would have been the case.

Comment: no prob, when there's a problem with one object only, the object panel is generally the best place to look :)